# file_get_contents should load after clicking a link

Tags: php

I'm passing a value to a string using the file_get_contents function as below:

```
$value=file_get_contents('http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?appId='.$app.'&from='.$fr.'&to='.$tol.'&text='.urlencode($lastline));

$speaktext="http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/http.svc/Speak?appId=$app&language=$tol&format=audio/wav&text=$value";
```

I'm using the variable $speaktext in the code below to output some sound out of it.

```
$sound="<object data=\"$speaktext\" classid=\"CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6\"width=\"200\" height=\"30\">
  <param name=\"url\" value=\"$text\"/>
  <param name=\"autostart\" value=\"false\"/>
</object>";
```

When I pass the $value variable to the $speaktext variable it first renders the whole $value variable (receives data from api.microsofttranslator.com) and the passes it to $speaktext.

Is there a way that the $value variable is rendered exactly when I use the `<object data=...>`?  I mean when the user clicks the play button on the `<object>`, It renders $value, passes it to $speaktext and the file will be played.

I know the question seems a bit hard to understand but I couldn't find a better way to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're asking for...so here are my assumptions

**1)** You have a page with a form, containing a textbox and button (lets call this `index.html`).

**2)** When the form is submitted, you want the page to speak the translated word from the textbox

**3)** The `file_get_contents...` etc exists in the file `text2speach.php`

**If that's the case, you'll probably want to use AJAX.**

In your `index.html`, make the form submit to `text2speach.php`, and add a form submit handler to make it use ajax instead. Then insert the returned HTML (`<object />`) into the page (and trigger a play() method if required. ).